how to use template without loss of style
I have a div-block with the "screen" id, an input field for text with the "message_text" id, and template with a design for a message in css.
template html code:
<template class="template_message" id="template_message">
      <div class="message">
            <p></p>
      </div>
</template>

js code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> {
    let button = document.getElementById("send_button");
    let template = document.getElementById("template_message");
    let screen = document.getElementById("screen");
    let message_text = document.getElementById("message_text");

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {

        let template_clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

        template_clone.textContent = message_text.value;

        screen.appendChild(template_clone);

    })
})

I am trying to output the value of the "message_text" field. what I just get is text without any css formatting

Show us your stylesheet.

You are being encouraged to update your question. If you do, please also include the HTML code for for the div-block you're saying you have. In general it is advised to create a minimal, reproducible example, which shouldn't be difficult, because that's what you already have.

Your issue is that .textContent sets the text content of the entire template, ie the html goes from
  <div class="message">
    <p></p>
  </div>

to just
message_text

Instead, you need to locate the .message > p element and change that element's textContent:
template_clone.querySelector(".message > p").textContent = message_text.value;

so the html becomes
  <div class="message">
      <p>message_text</p>
  </div>


Example snippet demonstrating the two:


let output1 = document.getElementById("output1");
let output2 = document.getElementById("output2");
let template = document.getElementById("template_message");

let clone1 = template.content.cloneNode(true);
// Replace entire template content
clone1.textContent = "New Message 1";
output1.appendChild(clone1, true);

let clone2 = template.content.cloneNode(true);
// Set just the message content
clone2.querySelector(".message > p").textContent = "New Message 2";
output2.appendChild(clone2);
.message { border:1px solid rebeccapurple; }
p { padding:0 0 0 3em; }
<template class="template_message" id="template_message">
      <div class="message">
            <p></p>
      </div>
</template>

<hr/>
<div id="output1"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="output2"></div>
<hr/>



